# Problem installing printers' drivers on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, epson, brother

Some time ago I tried to install my laser printer, a Brother hl-1112 and the installation appeared to be correct, but it only prints blank pages. Then, I decided to install my inkjet printer, an Epson stylus tx133, but it did not install. I've been searching for help in many sites since the problem started, but until now nothing has worked. Every time I turn on my computer, an error message appears related to the packages that hasn't installed completely from when I tried to install my Epson printer. Also, every time I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get the following error message:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 po-debconf
 debhelper
 alien
 librpmio3
 lsb-core
 lsb-graphics
 lsb-cxx
 lsb-multimedia
 lsb-desktop
 lsb-printing
 lsb-languages
 lsb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I need both printers working as soon as possible, can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: Try fixing your packages "sudo apt-get -f install" Then run update or "sudo apt-get upgrade"

Answer (score 1):

Download the Driver Install Tool:  [link](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=hl1112_us_eu&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625)
and follow the instructions bellow.

worked for my HL-1112 Ununto-Gnome 15.04

### From Brother Website ([link](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=hl1112_us_eu&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625)):

```
Step1. Download the tool.(linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz)

The tool will be downloaded into the default "Download" directory.
(The directory location varies depending on your Linux distribution.)
e.g. /home/(LoginName)/Download

Step2. Open a terminal window and go to the directory you downloaded the file to in the last step.

Step3. Enter this command to extract the downloaded file:

Command: gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz

Step4. Get superuser authorization with the "su" command or "sudo su" command.

Step5. Run the tool:

Command: bash linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-* Brother machine name

Step6. The driver installation will start. Follow the installation screen directions.


 When you see the message "Will you specify the DeviceURI ?",

 For USB Users: Choose N(No)
 For Network Users: Choose Y(Yes) and DeviceURI.

The install process may take some time. Please wait until it is complete.
```

Comment: Where are those quoted instructions from?  References...

Comment: It is referenced, 
"Download the Driver Install Tool: link and follow the instructions."
Where the instructions are from the referenced link.

Comment: OK, not clear from your answer that that is where they are from.  No issues.

Comment: Sorry about that, i will edit and make it clear.